# setsockopt for systemd unit - error: "Operation not permited"

Tags: systemd, setsockopt

I'm trying to run [BindToInterface](https://github.com/JsBergbau/BindToInterface) in a script as part of a systemd service that runs under its own separate user.

The service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Deluge Bittorrent Client Daemon
Documentation=man:deluged
After=network-online.target mnt-storage.mount
Requires=mnt-storage.mount
BindsTo=mnt-storage.mount

[Service]
Type=simple
UMask=000

ExecStart=/bin/bash /media/bti/deluged.sh

Restart=on-failure

# Time to wait before forcefully stopped.
TimeoutStopSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

BIND_INTERFACE=eno2 DNS_OVERRIDE_IP=8.8.8.8 BIND_EXCLUDE=127.0.0.1,192.168. LD_PRELOAD=/media/bti/bindToInterface.so /usr/bin/deluged -d -l /var/log/deluge/daemon.log -L warning
```

when executing:

```
systemctl status deluged
```

I get the following output:

```
bash[503711]: setsockopt: Operation not permitted
```

Is there a way to run your tool without elevated privileges? How would "setsockopt" be run for a systemd unit without elevated privileges

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Linux as a strict limitation: Only root can open ports below 1024. If your daemon is doing this, you can only do it by root.

Comment: As far as I understand, it does not (Deluge). Any workaround you might suggest? Thanks.